# Using a resolve in angular to get access to query string using $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to get `?ref=foo` attribute inside my login controller

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginController',
  resolve: {
    ref: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
      return $stateParams.ref;
    }]
  }
})
```

`$stateParams` is empty here.

```
//controller
.controller('LoginController', [
  '$scope',
  'ref',
  function($scope, ref){
```

Comment: huh? that's what I'm doing.

Comment: I found changing `url: '/login?ref'` works in both cases. That was all I needed.